# Eliminating equality constraints

Tags: convex-analysis

*The following text derived from book Convex Optimization, by Boyd, page 143*.

For a convex problem the equality constraints must be linear, i.e., of the form
$Ax = b$. In this case they can be eliminated by finding a particular solution $x_0$ of $Ax = b$, and a matrix $F$ whose range is the nullspace of $A$, which results in the
problem:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{z}{\text{minimize}}
& & f_0(Fz + x_0) \\
& \text{subject to}
& & f_i(Fz + x_0) \leq 0, \; i = 1, \ldots, m.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

my question:

> Which is the subspace logic in $Fz+x_0$ that makes this problem formulation equivalent to a convex optimization problem of the standard form with the affine  equality constraints?

Thank you!

Comment: You have $A(F z +x_0) = A x_0 = b$ for all $z$ and furthermore, if $Ax=b$ there is some $z$ such that $x=Fz+x_0$.

Comment: Could you please explain a little more why the $A(Fx+x_0)=Ax_0$ is true? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the optimization problem as such, it is just
a way of parametrising the set $S = \{ x | Ax=b\}$.

Suppose ${\cal R} F = \ker A$ and $x_0 \in S$.
Since $x_0 \in S$ we have $Ax_0 = b$.

Then $x \in S$ **iff** $Ax=b$ **iff** $Ax = A x_0$ **iff** $x-x_0 \in \ker A$
**iff** $x-x_0 \in {\cal R}F$ **iff** $x \in \{ x_0+F y \}_y$.

That is, $S = \{ x_0+F y \}_y$ (that is all points of the form $x_0+Fy$ for some
$y$ in the domain of $F$).

Hence if we have some problem ${\cal P}: \ \min \{ f_0(x) | f_i(x) \le 0, Ax=b \}$, it is equivalent to solving
${\cal P}':  \ \min \{ f_0(x_0+Fy) | f_i(x_0+Fy) \le 0 \}$, the difference
being that the constraint $x \in S$ is implicitly enforced in ${\cal P}'$.

Comment: Ok I think I got it!

Comment: Do you have any idea how $F$ can be obtained? I heard from someone I can use the SVD decomposition of $A$, but I've not been successful in finding out how.

Comment: Maybe use the QR decomposition?